# ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object (Laravel Framework)

Tags: php, database, laravel, exception, solr

I'm getting an error while the Solr is working fine. I checked using the IP and port and HTML is opening. Since I'm new to Laravel and Solr can't understand what's going on. I just migrated WebApp from one VM to another. And I starts facing this issue. Application using Laravel 5.2 and running on CentOS7.2

> ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /srv/websites/webapp.com/app/webapp/Solr/Solr.php:248

Here is a complete error from Laravel Logs.

```
[2016-10-15 00:33:57] production.ERROR: ErrorException: Trying to get property of non-object in /srv/websites/webapp.com/app/webapp/Solr/Solr.php:248
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/websites/webapp.com/app/webapp/Solr/Solr.php(248): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get p...', '/srv/websites/r...', 248, Array)
#1 /srv/websites/webapp.com/app/Http/Controllers/SearchController.php(39): App\webapp\Solr\Solr->search(Array)
#2 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\SearchController->getSearchResponse()
#3 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9424): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9486): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('getSearchRespon...', Array)
#5 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9466): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->call(Object(App\Http\Controllers\SearchController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), 'getSearchRespon...')
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 /srv/websites/webapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#8 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9948): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#10 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9467): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#11 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9454): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(Object(App\Http\Controllers\SearchController), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'getSearchRespon...')
#12 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8524): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), 'App\\Http\\Contro...', 'getSearchRespon...')
#13 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8511): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8225): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#16 /srv/websites/webapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9948): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#19 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8226): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#20 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8217): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(8207): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2419): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /srv/websites/webapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(52): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#25 /srv/websites/webapp.com/app/Http/Middleware/Wizard.php(14): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\Wizard->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#27 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9963): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#28 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 /srv/websites/webapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 /srv/websites/webapp.com/app/Http/Middleware/LoginRedirect.php(15): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\LoginRedirect->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9963): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#33 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#34 /srv/websites/webapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 /srv/websites/webapp.com/app/Http/Middleware/Analytics.php(20): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\Analytics->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#37 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9963): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#38 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 /srv/websites/webapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#40 /srv/websites/webapp.com/app/Http/Middleware/ClientInit.php(23): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\ClientInit->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#42 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9963): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#43 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 /srv/websites/webapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#45 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13474): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#46 [internal function]: Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#47 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9963): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#48 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#49 /srv/websites/webapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(11964): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#51 [internal function]: Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#52 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9963): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#53 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#54 /srv/websites/webapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#55 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13213): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#56 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#57 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9963): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#58 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#59 /srv/websites/webapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#60 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(13150): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#61 [internal function]: Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#62 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9963): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#63 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#64 /srv/websites/webapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#65 /srv/websites/webapp.com/app/Http/Middleware/Debug.php(19): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#66 [internal function]: App\Http\Middleware\Debug->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#67 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9963): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#68 [internal function]: Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#69 /srv/websites/webapp.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(32): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#70 [internal function]: Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#71 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(9948): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#72 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2366): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#73 /srv/websites/webapp.com/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php(2350): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#74 /srv/websites/webapp.com/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#75 {main}
```

Here is Solr.php file contains

```
<?php

namespace App\webapp\Solr;

use Config;

class Solr
{
    public static $ROWS_PER_PAGE = 8;
    private $curl;
    private $collection;
    private $first = false;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $host = config('solr.host').':'.config('solr.port', 3000);
        $this->curl = \Curl::create($host);
        $this->curl->addQuery('wt', 'json');
        $this->collection = config('solr.collection');
    }

    public function select()
    {
        return new self();
    }

    public function analysis($id)
    {
        $this->curl->addQuery('q', "id:Analysis-$id");

        return $this;
    }

    public function piece()
    {
        $this->curl->addQuery('q', 'type_primary:research or type_primary:outlook or type_primary:media');

        return $this;
    }

    public function event($id)
    {
        $this->curl->addQuery('q', "id:CMS-Events-$id");

        return $this;
    }

    public function citation($id)
    {
        $this->curl->addQuery('q', "id:CMS-Citation-$id");

        return $this;
    }

    public function thought($id)
    {
        $this->curl->addQuery('q', "id:CMS-Thought-$id");

        return $this;
    }

    public function keyword($keyword)
    {
        $this->curl->addQuery('fq', "keywords:\"$keyword\"");

        return $this;
    }

    public function fq($fq)
    {
        $this->curl->addQuery('fq', $fq);

        return $this;
    }

    public function first()
    {
        $this->first = true;

        return $this;
    }

    public function order($order)
    {
        $this->curl->addQuery('sort', $order);

        return $this;
    }

    public function skip($rows)
    {
        $this->curl->addQuery('start', $rows);

        return $this;
    }

    public function take($rows)
    {
        $this->curl->addQuery('rows', $rows);

        return $this;
    }

    public function retrieve()
    {
        $this->curl->addQuery('fl', implode(',', func_get_args()));

        return $this;
    }

    public function search($params, $debug = false)
    {

        # Loose query search using edismax query builder.
        $q = (isset($params['q']) && !empty($params['q'])) ? $params['q'] : '*:*';

        # If page is set
        $p = (isset($params['p']) && !empty($params['p'])) ? intval(abs($params['p'])) : 0;

        # Query filter weights for edismax
        $qf = [
            'authors^40',
            'keyword_primary^30',
            'keywords^20',
            'fulltext^10',
        ]; # = 100 Weight Total, Perfect Score

        # Boost Query
        $bq = [];
        if (isset($params['regions-geographic']) && is_array($params['regions-geographic'])) {
            foreach ($params['regions-geographic'] as $k => $v) {
                $bq[] = "keyword_primary:\"{$v}\"";
            }
        }
        if (isset($params['regions-economic']) && is_array($params['regions-economic'])) {
            foreach ($params['regions-economic'] as $k => $v) {
                $bq[] = "keyword_primary:\"{$v}\"";
            }
        }
        if (isset($params['topics']) && is_array($params['topics'])) {
            foreach ($params['topics'] as $k => $v) {
                $bq[] = "keyword_primary:\"{$v}\"";
            }
        }
        if (isset($params['authors']) && is_array($params['authors'])) {
            foreach ($params['authors'] as $k => $v) {
                $bq[] = "authors:\"{$v}\"";
            }
        }
        if (!empty($params['primary-keyword'])) {
            $bq[] = "(keyword_primary:\"{$params['primary-keyword']}\" OR authors:\"{$params['primary-keyword']}\")";
        }

        # Filter Query
        $fq1 = [];
        if (isset($params['regions-geographic']) && is_array($params['regions-geographic'])) {
            foreach ($params['regions-geographic'] as $k => $v) {
                $fq1[] = "keywords:\"{$v}\"";
            }
        }
        if (isset($params['regions-economic']) && is_array($params['regions-economic'])) {
            foreach ($params['regions-economic'] as $k => $v) {
                $fq1[] = "keywords:\"{$v}\"";
            }
        }
        if (isset($params['topics']) && is_array($params['topics'])) {
            foreach ($params['topics'] as $k => $v) {
                $fq1[] = "keywords:\"{$v}\"";
            }
        }
        if (isset($params['authors']) && is_array($params['authors'])) {
            foreach ($params['authors'] as $k => $v) {
                $fq1[] = "authors:\"{$v}\"";
            }
        }
        if (!empty($params['primary-keyword'])) {
            $fq1[] = "(keywords:\"{$params['primary-keyword']}\" OR authors:\"{$params['primary-keyword']}\")";
        }

        $fq2 = [];
        if (isset($params['content']) && is_array($params['content'])) {
            foreach ($params['content'] as $k => $v) {
                $fq2[] = "type_secondary:\"{$v}\"";
            }
        }

        # Content Template Filter
        $fq = '';
        if (!empty($fq1)):
            $fq .= '('.implode(' AND ', $fq1).')';
        if (!empty($fq2)) {
            $fq .= ' AND ';
        }
        endif;

        if (!empty($fq2)):
            $fq .= '('.implode(' OR ', $fq2).')';
        endif;

        # Minimum match required for return.
        $mm = 3;

        # Sort by score and then date created.
        //$sort="score desc, date_created desc";
        $sort = 'date_created desc';

        # List Filter for Objects
        $fl = 'page_title, url_absolute, date_created, date_unix_created, authors_primary, keyword_primary, keywords, type_primary, type_secondary';

        $this->curl->addQuery('defType', 'edismax');
        $this->curl->addQuery('q', $q);
        $this->curl->addQuery('qf', implode(' ', $qf));
        if (!empty($bq)) {
            $this->curl->addQuery('bq', implode(' OR ', $bq));
        }
        if (!empty($fq)) {
            $this->curl->addQuery('fq', $fq);
        }
        $this->curl->addQuery('mm', $mm);
        $this->curl->addQuery('sort', $sort);
        $this->curl->addQuery('start', $p * self::$ROWS_PER_PAGE);
        $this->curl->addQuery('rows', self::$ROWS_PER_PAGE);
        $this->curl->addQuery('fl', $fl);

        if ($debug) {
            echo "<pre style='word-wrap: break-word;'>";
            echo "Params:\n";
            var_dump($params);
            echo "Q:\n";
            var_dump($q);
            echo "QF:\n";
            var_dump($qf);
            echo "FQ:\n";
            var_dump($fq);
            echo "SORT:\n";
            var_dump($sort);
            echo "FL:\n";
            var_dump($fl);
            echo "Response:\n";
            var_dump($this->get(true, true));
            echo '</pre>';
            exit();
        }

        $response = $this->get(false, true);

        $r = [];
        $r['total'] = $response->response->numFound;
        $r['pages'] = ceil($response->response->numFound / self::$ROWS_PER_PAGE);
        $r['page'] = intval(abs($p));
        $r['rows'] = self::$ROWS_PER_PAGE;
        $r['docs'] = (isset($response->response->docs) && !empty($response->response->docs)) ? $response->response->docs : [];

        return $r;
    }

    public function get($debug = false, $raw = false)
    {
        $this->curl->setUri('solr', $this->collection, 'select');
        $response = $this->curl->get(array(
            'dataType' => \App\webapp\Curl\Curl::TYPE_JSON,
        ));

        if ($debug) {
            echo "\n<strong>".urldecode($this->curl->lastUrl())."</strong>\n";
        }
        if (!isset($response->response)) {
            return [];
        }

        $this->convertDatesToCarbon($response);

        if ($raw) {
            return $response;
        }

        return $this->first ? reset($response->response->docs) : $response->response->docs;
    }

    private function convertDatesToCarbon(&$response)
    {
        foreach ($response->response->docs as $doc) {
            if (isset($doc->created)) {
                $doc->created = new \Carbon\Carbon($doc->created);
            }
            if (isset($doc->modified)) {
                $doc->modified = new \Carbon\Carbon($doc->modified);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Line 248 is....

Comment: If you open the actual URL that curl requests - what's the response? Does the log in Solr show anything useful (aka an error or show that the request is being made)?

Comment: Line 248 is $r['total'] = $response->response->numFound; @Devon

Comment: How to open actual URL that requests. Can you tell me more about this? I installed on VM but have not configured in that. @MatsLindh

Comment: @vikaskumawat80 So the error means `$response->response` isn't an object.  Dump out `$response` and see what it is, then debug.

Comment: @Devon the same code working fine in my production VM in Rackspace I'm trying to migrate to Azure. After migration, I'm getting this. Do you have any idea what thing can cause this type of problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe only the problem is

```
$response->response->numFound
```

Test with

```
$response->numFound
```

And you can add this for prevent the Error: "Trying to get property of non-object in "

```
$r['total'] = (property_exists($response), 'numFound') ? $response->numFound : null;
```